# SharePoint Online out of the box search box is showing modified date in English US format (MM/DD/YYYY) rather than (DD/MM/YYY)

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-search

SharePoint Online out-of-the-box search box is showing date in English US format (MM/DD/YYYY) rather than English UK format (DD/MM/YYYY).

I have checked the site's regional setting and it says English (United Kingdom) so

I am not sure why this is happening.

[image: Please see the example]

Has anyone had this issue before, and if so, how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test,I can reproduce your issue in my end:
[image]

I would suggest you go to UserVoice to make your suggestions:

[Allow language and date formats on search results page to be changed](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/41471629-allow-language-and-date-formats-on-search-results)